# incompatability of the ternary operator

Tags: gcc, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

```
#define BIT2 (1 << 2) 
#define BIT0 (1 << 0) 

unsigned int a = 0, temp = 0;

#define setBit2_a (a |= BIT2) 
#define clearBit2_a (a &= ~BIT2)

#define setBit0_a (a |= BIT0) 
#define clearBit0_a (a &= ~BIT0)
void main()
{
    a=4; //use a scanf here for convinient
    temp = a;

    a & BIT0 != 0 ? setBit2_a : clearBit2_a;
    temp & BIT2 != 0 ? setBit0_a : clearBit0_a;        

    printf("the number entered is a = %u\n\r", a);
}
```

this should set the bit 0 in the variable a , but its not doing so in ubuntu gcc complier can anybody please explain this

Comment: What is the architecture and what IS the value defined for BIT0 and what is type for a?

Comment: Your code doesn't work: First of all, `if (a = 4)` always returns `true`. Secondly, a can never be `4` at all in your example. Thirdly, you're not assigning the result of your ternary statement to anything, so what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

all that is to be noted here is:
the operator precedence for == is stronger than for & so the evaluated results which is always false and we need to use the braces here in accordance with the precedence and the BODMAS rule.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you probably expect a different result from your expression `a & (1 << 2) != 0`: the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for `==` is stronger than for `&` so the evalution results in `a & ((1 << 2) != 0)` which is always `false` for your ternary operator since `4 & 1 == 0`

You want: `(a & (1 << 2)) != 0 ? ...;` or `a & 4 ? ...;`